# How to access ajax response data outside ajax function in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I am fetching some data via http get ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/userdata/",

    success: function(response){
        $scope.steps = response.no_of_steps;
        $scope.calories = response.calories;
    },

    error: function(){
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

If i print it on console from inside the success function, it prints the value like:

```
    success: function(response){
        var $scope.steps = response.no_of_steps;
        var $scope.calories = response.calories;
        console.log($scope.steps, $scope.calories);
    },
```

But if i print it on colsole outside my ajax request, it print undefined. how is that so?

```
$.ajax({
    ...
});
console.log($scope.steps, $scope.calories);
```

Comment: First of all, why are you using jQuery ajax functions when you have [Angular's](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)?

Secondly when you put var before $scope.steps you're creating a new $scope variable inside that function, it won't exist outside the function (your undefined).

Comment: you don't need the var before your variable name. Remove it and check again

Comment: the problem is you are `logging` `$scope.steps` and  `$scope.calories` before your `success` of ajax. If you really want them on `console` you have got to wait for your `ajax` call to complete

Comment: i have posted my answer below

Comment: and what's the result of `alert`in success callback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this is continuation of my `comment` on your post above**

you could do that by using `$scope.$emit("custom-event-name");` of `angular`,
here you are actually watching `$scope.steps` and `$scope.calories` for `change` once your `ajax` call completes signify this by using `$emit` of `angular`

and then listen for that event by `$scope.$on("custom-event-name", function(){})`

and `log` it there, Please do make sure your `"custom-event-name"` is same in `$emit` and `$on`

in `success` callback : initialize the value and use `$emit` to emit an event named `initialized` as :-

```
$scope.steps = response.no_of_steps;
$scope.calories = response.calories;
$scope.$emit("initialized");
```

and then listen for that event `initialized`

```
$scope.$on('initialized', function () { 
  console.log($scope.steps + ' and ' + $scope.calories);
});
```

Comment: Its not printing anything on console

Comment: best way it to use 'debugger'

Comment: well the simplest of all, as i see for you, is to put an `alert` of response in `success` callback and in both the `$scope.$watch` before `if` with a valid identification message

Comment: alert before if condition is working but alert after if condition is not working

Comment: good! keep going, you're on right track... what's the `alert` value ? if it is what you need purpose served if not `customize` the `if`

Comment: It is printing undefined for both steps and calories.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109640/discussion-between-manish-and-user0706).

Answer (score 0):

Couple of mistakes here.... use `$http` instead of `$ajax`, secondly you are defining your variables inside your `success function` so the scope is limited once it comes out of it... define your `function globally` in your `controller` and then access it inside your success function.

```
var $scope.steps => wrong way
$scope.steps = "something"; => right way.
```

You don't need to append `var` keyword with `$scope` in angularjs.

```
$scope.steps;
$scope.calories;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/userdata/",

    success: function(response){
        $scope.steps = response.no_of_steps;
        $scope.calories = response.calories;
    },

    error: function(){
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Use `$scope variables` if you want to bind to the view and `var` does not and is local to the function it was declared in.

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't work. I removed the var and replaced ajax with http and defined the variables globally but it is still showing undefined

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, i want to recommend you not to make use of $.ajax in angular js its a jquery function; i heard $http is faster than $.ajax function.

Hope this works for you if didnot work please inform me

```
//$scope.tablerows defined outside the function 
$scope.tablerows;
module='user';
url=siteurl+"/admin/"+module+"/list";
BlockUi();
// $http is ajax call in angular js which is equivalent to $.ajax();
$http({
    url     :   url,
    method  :   "GET",
    data    :   "",
    headers : { 'Content-Type':undefined,
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
              }
    //responseText is the output of success call
    }).then(function(responseText){
        // assigning the response text on the variable 
        $scope.totaltablerows=responseText.data.response_data;
        $scope.tablerows=$scope.totaltablerows;
        UnblockUi();
    },function(error){
        //alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        UnblockUi();
        UnknownError(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```